# Plotting a stacked Bar Chart in pandas for multiple x-axis attributes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, stacked-chart

l have four bars in my histogram which represent the frequency of **letter, digit, special characters** and alphnumeric in my file.

l did the following to get the frequency of each family :

```
def  group_data():
    def find_group(val):
        val = str(val)
        val = val.lower()

        if val.isalpha():
            return 'alphabet'
        elif val.isdigit():
            return 'digit'
        elif val.isalnum and any(c.isalpha() for c in val) and any(c.isdigit() for c in val):

            return 'alphanum'
        else:
            return 'spec-char'


    df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=',')
    df = df.astype(str)
    df.manual_raw_value = df.manual_raw_value.str.lower()
    df.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group)
    df.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group).value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

and l got the following for 
the `first file and second file` 
[image]

Now l would like to get a stacked bar so l did the following

```
normal = df.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group).value_counts()
aug=df2.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group).value_counts()
sub_df = pd.concat([normal, aug], keys=["alphabet", "digit","spec-char","alpha-num"]).unstack()
sub_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=1)
plt.show()
```

However, l got a wrong plot

**EDIT-1**
I'm supposed to get plot like the following: 
[image]
red bars for

```
aug=df2.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group).value_counts()
```

and blue bars for

```
normal = df.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group).value_counts()
```

Comment: What should the stack plot look like?

Comment: You cannot say "I get the wrong plot" and then show the plot. Instead you need to tell us *what* is wrong with the plot you get and *how*  you would like it to look instead.

Comment: @ScottBoston,  please see my edit . thank you

Comment: Okay.  let's try `sub_df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=1)`